# Running batch script with two msiexec commands causes finishing script just after finishing first command

Tags: windows, git, batch-file, jenkins, spawning

I am trying to run batch script from jenkins job which has two msiexec commands one for uninstallation and other for installation.
This script is on github so jenkins job clone the repo and then run the script

Jenkins job start execution of second msiexec (installation) command but it ends immediately.If i open Job console i can see message "Process leaked file descriptors." and job status : Success

If i run The same script through cmd without jenkins it is working fine.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
IF EXIST "directory path" (
msiexec /uninstall {Product ID} /qb
)
pushd \\shared drive
IF EXIST "directory path" (
msiexec /i "path to exefile" /qb
popd
exit 0
)
ELSE (
ECHO Setup Not Found in current
exit 0
)
```

Comment: It's odd that it works in cmd, unless there's stuff you're not showing us because the structure of your command is wrong. See [here](http://pastebin.com/WVJcJfUe)

Comment: No there is no extra stuff , i am using only these two commands for install/uninstall and yes if i run same script after cloning thru cmd its working fine

Comment: Did you look at the two examples I posted in the link, neither of them are what you posted and one of them is likely to be correct. I do not know which one and without the correct structure debugging is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword **ELSE** must be on same line as `)` of TRUE branch of **IF** condition separated from `)` by a space character. The **ELSE** on a separate line is interpreted like name of a console application to run.

```
if exist "directory path" (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\msiexec.exe /uninstall {Product ID} /qb
)
pushd "\\ComputerName\ShareName\"
if exist "directory path" (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\msiexec.exe /i "path to exefile" /qb
) else (
    echo Setup not found in %CD%.
)
popd
exit /B 0
```

**Hint:** For debugging a batch file run it from within a command prompt window and not with double clicking on it after removing or commenting all lines containing `echo off`. And don't use **EXIT** without `/B` as this results always in exiting entire command process and not only in exiting just processing of current batch file. Debugging a batch file in a command prompt window becomes difficult if the batch file contains **EXIT** without `/B` and this command is really executed on running the batch file because error messages output during running the batch file can't be seen in this case.